# execute function when a one cell changes but not another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, static, refresh, formula

I have calculated values in the column of cells 'N', and each cell has the following function (I am showing the function for the first applicable row N12):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(F12),QUOTIENT(F12-ProjectStartDate+1,ProjectIncrements),"")
```

In an excel sheet, I want N12 (and all other cells in column N from row 12 to the last row) to refresh the function if the value in column F changes on the same row, or if ProjectStartDate changes, but *NOT* if ProjectIncrements changes.  In other words, I do not want to refresh the formulas in column N when the user changes the value of ProjectIncrements.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes with vba.  Formulas are live and if the inputs change so does the output.  But with vba one can create events that fire only when wanted.

Comment: Not without VBA. Create a separate ProjectIncrements, say StaticProjectIncrements, which the user doesn't change and you'll be fine.